# how to speed up map insertion?

Tags: c++11, stl, stdmap

Looks like I finally improved a little map insertion speed (sorting before inserting). What do you think about these results ? Are there anymore optimisations ?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  //a map<size_t, size_t> random initilisation
  std::map<size_t, size_t> m0, m1;
  {
     std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> > t (10000, std::pair<size_t, size_t> ((size_t) -1, (size_t) -1));
     std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> >::iterator i (t.begin ());
     for (; i != t.end (); ++i) {
       i->first = rand () % 1000000;
       i->second = rand () %1;
     }
     m0.insert (t.begin (), t.end ());
     m1 = m0;
   }
   //vins :
   std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> > vins (10000, std::pair<size_t, size_t> (0, 0));
   {
     std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> >::iterator i (vins.begin ());
     for (; i != vins.end (); ++i) {
       i->first = rand () % 1000000;
       i->second = rand () %1;
     }
   }
   //normal insertion
   clock_t t0 (clock ()), t1 (t0);
   {
     m0.insert (vins.begin (), vins.end ());
   }
   t1 = clock ();
   std::cout << "normal insertion took " << (size_t) (t1 -  t0) << " ticks" << std::endl;
   //sort + hint insertion
   t0 = t1;
   {
     std::sort (vins.begin (), vins.end (), [] (std::pair<size_t, size_t>& p0, std::pair<size_t, size_t>& p1)->bool {
       return (p0.first < p1.first ? true:false);
     });
     std::map<size_t, size_t>::iterator ihint (m1.begin ());
     //std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t> >::iterator i (vins.begin ());
     //imroved and more C++11 solution
     std::for_each (vins.begin (), vins.end (), [&ihint, &m1] (std::pair<size_t, size_t>& p) {
       ihint = m1.insert (ihint, p);
     });
   }
   t1 = clock ();
   std::cout << "insertion after sorting took " << (size_t) (t1 - t0) << " ticks" << std::endl;
   if (m0 != m1) std::cout << "but insertion is nok" << std::endl;
   else std::cout << "and insertion is ok" << std::endl;
}
```

A result on a Lenovo Think Centre :

insertion took 2355 ticks

sort then insertion took 1706 ticks

and insertion is ok

Comment: If you don't require the ordering property, then `std::unordered_map` may be faster. Also ensure compiler optimisation is turned on (usually `-O2` or `-O3`). On my machine, using these improved performance by a factor of 3 for the normal hint insertion and knocked a few hundred ticks off the 2nd result. Finally, this may be more suitable for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am usiing -Ofast, but I believed std::map was better at find than std::unordered_map. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @hnefatl I deleted my comment because a type made my question vague. I was primarily interested if there is a compiler optimisation which can make these maps faster. so if I am using an `std::unordered_map` already, can I make it faster using a possible compiler optimisation ?

Comment: @Saint-Martin Nope, `unordered_map` is implemented using a hashtable, which provides average-time `O(1)` insertion and find operations, compared to `map` which provides `O(log n)` for both. In practice, the difference is noticeable as `unordered_map` has (I think) better cache-locality than `map`, which boosts the performance even more.

Comment: @TitoHamzee I don't think the optimisation level will effect the speed of the map (the standard library has already been compiled), but it might be able to unroll some loops or force copy-elision or perform a touch more static analysis in  *this* code, which will reduce overhead anyway. As always with optimisations, it's better to just try it - and on my machine, it does lead to a performance increase.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur answer. But map find is O (ln (n)), is not it ?

Comment: @Saint-Martin Yes, `map` has `O(log n)` find (see the "complexity" section [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/)). Note that `O(ln n)` is equivalent to `O(log n)`, as the two are only different by a constant factor.

Comment: It would be an easier example to test ourselves if you added your includes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need your items to be ordered, then using [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)  is usually a better choice than `std::map` - it uses a hashtable rather than a balanced tree in most implementations, which means that operations are on average `O(1)` rather than `O(log n)`. In addition, it can have a performance boost from cache-locality, as the underlying data structure (array) is usually more cache-friendly than a tree.

Enabling `-O3` (or similar optimisation level) might increase the performance of *your* code, but is unlikely to effect the performance of the map's insertion/find operations (as it's already been compiled). Bear in mind that using `-Ofast` means the compiler no longer needs to strictly adhere to the standards, which is usually not a great idea - use it if performance is critical and you've checked your code works as expected with it, but usually `-O3` is enough.

---

On my machine (Debian, g++ 6.3.0), using a few runs and taking rough averages:

```
 Configuration             Normal Hint Insertion   Hint Insertion  
 ------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- 
  std::map,           -O0                    9750             9200  
  std::map,           -O3                    8000             4250  
  std::unordered_map, -O0                    7000             9700  
  std::unordered_map, -O3                    4200             5000
```

Comment: So unordered map normal insertion (4200) is a little better than hint insertion on a normal map (4250).

Comment: @Saint-Martin Yep, on my machine - I'd guess that the work you do in the hint insertion is adding overhead to the insertion but not helping speed up the insertion itself. You're sorting the data in the hint insertion, and as `std::unordered_map` isn't ordered, that's probably not helping at all.

Comment: My question was about ordered map. Sorry

Comment: @Saint-Martin Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the meaning of your comment.